# where does feature_names is Scikit-learn come from?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am learning scikit-learn and I ran this code, which imports the breast cancer csv

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer_data = load_breast_cancer()
#print(cancer_data.DESCR)
```

When I run `cancer_data.keys()`, it brings back the following:

```
dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'frame', 'target_names', 'DESCR', 'feature_names', 'filename'])
```

There are no column headers in this csv, yet running `cancer_data.feature_names` gives me a list of column names. Where is this information coming from?

thanks

Comment: If your question is resolved, please choose one of the answers to accept so it gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

These names are define in the `load_breast_cancer()` function. See [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15cb8695a27eb8d4dc281ac3c937e12db8b5a6c1/sklearn/datasets/_base.py#L511) for details.

In [original source](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+(Diagnostic)) data file doesn't have columns names, there is separate file with description of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `type(cancer_data)` to check what is the type of your data you will get something like this `sklearn.utils.Bunch` and according to the official [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.Bunch.html) `Bunch` objects are sometimes used as an output for functions and methods. They extend dictionaries by enabling values to be accessed by key, bunch["value_key"], or by an attribute, bunch.value_key.

Since they extend [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) you can use `cancer_data.keys()` to get the keys which is what you are getting as an output.

> Follow the links to know more